# too many menu items to display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made a horizontal navigation menu for a clients website which is responsive. When screen size is beneath 800px there is a simplified menu which toggles.

My clients filled his menu with numerous items, my opinion too much, and not all of the menu items are correctly displayed when it's shown in normal screen mode, it results in a new menu line which is not desired.

Most of the times I think it will all fit the user's screen but when screen size is less than 1366px wide, there will be problems displaying the menu the right way.

[website](http://www.zandstraalwerken.be)

Can I fix this issue with pure css?

The other option is to use some scripting.

Could I use jquery to check if there are list items off screen and then modify css?
(I really don't have experience with jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use media query to change menu when screen size is smaller than 1366 px and try to convert few menu items in sub menu it will help in minimizing width of navigation bar

Comment: I created extra media queries for correct display, thnx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You cant fix this in pure css and you can't create a responsive code for all browsers. Jquery can help you to resolve this issue. and if you don't know much more about jquery than get a simple navigation menu code and apply it